# Angular $interval without scope refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, setinterval, karma-runner

I have a $interval in an Angular service which check if an array is empty or not and run a script on each data of the array. This is something quite simple. My problem is that each time the $interval is running my scope is refreshed an few directives are "run again". If I use a javascript setInterval function instead of $interval, the result is what I expect. But I would like to use $interval since I don't know how to mock calls to setInteval while running karma tests.
Any ideas on how to use $interval for this need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know for sure without seeing your code, but I believe you could set the 4th parameter (`invokeApply`) to `false` when calling `$interval`. That should prevent the behind-the-scenes call to `$scope.$apply()`, which I believe is what's happening here.

See the [$interval documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) for more details.

Comment: I already tried this solution but it's not working. Scope continue to be refresh at each interval. Sorry I'm not allowed to post any code :-(

Comment: Would it be possible for you to reproduce the behavior in a barebones example, without posting actual company-owned code? You could use this JSFiddle as a starting template: http://jsfiddle.net/troygizzi/L0m1udsy/

Comment: Here is a fiddle on which I reproduced the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/L0m1udsy/12/ As you can see in the log the directive is run each second because of interval on the controller. (we see url loaded in logs each second)

Comment: Turns out the `invokeApply` parameter was not working as designed in versions 1.2.x and earlier. I updated that JSFiddle to use version 1.3.1, and added the `, 0, false` parameters in the call to `$interval`, and that seems to fix it. Here are the [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/troygizzi/L0m1udsy/13/), the [bug report](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7103), and the [fix](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/7988).

Comment: Can @TroyGizzi you explain why log 'url loaded' is called 4 times please ? explain why log 'url loaded' is called 4 times please in your fidlle http://jsfiddle.net/troygizzi/L0m1udsy/13/ ?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. I'm not sure why that happens, but if you set the URL as a $scope property directly in the `controller` function, instead of nesting it in a `getUrl` function called from the directive, then it only gets executed once. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/troygizzi/L0m1udsy/15/ (I suspect that the directive itself may still be getting run multiple times when the page first loads, but at least this avoids the URL-setting code from being executed multiple times as well.)

Comment: I asked the question in another post. Here is the answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777699/need-explanation-on-a-angular-direcive-load/26777902?noredirect=1#comment42135311_26777902