# Need explanation on a angular direcive load

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I just want to understand why in the following jsFiddle 'here is a lo' is printed three times.

http://jsfiddle.net/wg385a1h/5/

```
$scope.getLog = function () {
    console.log('here is a log');
 }
```

Can someone explain me why ? What should I change to have only one log "here is a log" (that's what I would like this fiddle do). Thanks a lot.

Comment: A good starting point: https://www.ng-book.com/p/The-Digest-Loop-and-apply/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular uses digest cycles/iterations to determine when state has changed and needs to update the UI. If it finds any change on one of it's cycles, it keeps rerunning cycles until the data stabilizes itself. If it's done 10 cycles and the data is still changing, you'll see a rather know message: "angularjs 10 iterations reached. aborting".

Therefor, The fact that you are seeing the message displayed 3 times is because you have a simple interface. In fact, you can get up to many more such messages in the log, due to the fact that your directive uses {{getLog()}}. Angular keeps evaluating the expression to see if it changed.

To avoid such problems, under normal circumstances, you should store the value returned by the function you want called only once in the $scope object inside the controller and use that variable (not the function call) in the UI.

So in the controller you'd have $scope.log = getLog() [assuming it returns something, and not just writing to the console] and in the directive use the template {{log}}. This way, you'll get the value only once, per controller instance.

Hope I was clear enough.

Comment: OK, indeed I already get this. But what about if the function take an argument and is called in a ng-repeat (different arg in each repeat) ? How do you write such a function call please ? here is an example : http://jsfiddle.net/wg385a1h/12/

Comment: in that case, I'd recommend rethinking the entire model. Because having a function being called only once per argument used in the UI is a bit wonky.

Comment: You could build an object which holds information needed for the UI, for that specific component... call all the functions you need to initialize it and store results inside the object. Then just use that object in the UI. That way, angular's iterations won't trigger unwanted functions and you have your date stored in a practical manner, that you can change if needed.